# spring security authentication required page

Tags: security, spring, authentication

I use Spring Security 3.0.7

I have a web security rule in the config file to allow the access to some pages just to authenticated users:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

When an anonymous user tries to access any of those pages, the login form is rendered, in order to enter the usename and password.

This is the default behaviour.

But is there any way to render a custom page instead of the login form? (for example, a page just showing a message like "Access denied")

Answer (score 0):

As it is written in Spring Security Documentation (section 9.2) you can specify accessDeniedHandler which could handle the 403 error (forbidden):

```
<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
     class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
  <property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.htm"/>
</bean>
```

Further in point 9.2.2 you can read:

> By default, an AccessDeniedHandlerImpl is used, which just sends a 403 (Forbidden) response to the client. Alternatively you can configure an instance explicitly (as in the above example) and set an error page URL which it will forwards the request to. This can be a simple “access denied” page, such as a JSP, or it could be a more complex handler such as an MVC controller. And of course, you can implement the interface yourself and use your own implementation.

Comment: But I think AccessDeniedHandler and the error page you set in it, is for request that are not authorizated (that is, users that are authenticated but don't have the roles required to access the resource), isn't it? But my case is different (users that are not authenticated and try to access a resource whose access is restricted to authenticated users). I think in my case doesn't redirect to the page you say.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. In this situation I have an idea that not authenticated user could obtain some role, i.e ROLE_GUEST but as far as I know, Spring Security does not provide such solution out of the box, so one has to extend security system by implementing own class.

Comment: Spring Security has a default role for not authenticated users. It's the IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY role, but it isn't useful for my purpose. However, I'm thinking that if I change the web security rule, using a role that all the authenticated users have (for example ROLE_USER), instead of using "isAuthenticated()", maybe then if a not authenticated user tries to access it, he/her should be redirected to the custom accessDenied page, instead of to the login page. That would be what I want. I have to try it.

Comment: I use that scenario in my application. Unfortunately - not authenticated user is redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your access denied page via

```
<form-login login-page="/accessDenied.htm" />
```

To enable "normal login", you have to wire up another page which submits its login form to /j_spring_security_check (if you don't change the defaults).

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `authentication-failure-url` attribute to `form-login` tag?

```
<form-login login-page="/login.htm"
                        default-target-url="/successview.htm"
                        always-use-default-target="true"
                        authentication-failure-url = "/accessdenied.htm?login_error=1" />
```